# Itext rich media annotation with multiple assets in different locations or folder structure

Tags: itext, rich-media

Is it possible to add a main swf file which is supported by other files in a certain folder structure.
I'm actually trying to implement an articulate storyline project composed of 9 files (swf, xml, jpg, mp3, js)in three different directories.
I found some resources but I was not able to provide the supported files to the main swf. I always get the message that the next file in the chain cannot be loaded. 
i.e.: story.swf requires data.swf  to load which further needs meta.xml which requires the thumbnail.jpg which is located in the sub directory story_content...
So bottom line I need to add assets in a certain directory structure. 
Can you please help me out on that.
Thank you very much for your help. 
Kind Regards, Mario

Comment: Flash/Flex/swf in PDF will be deprecated in PDF 2.0 (ISO-32000-2). Hence you should not expect any more answers regarding this type of rich media. Soon PDF viewers will no longer support it (and PDF viewers that didn't support it won't do any effort to start supporting it).

Comment: so it won't be possible even not with using a RichMediaAnnotation

Comment: Because this is why I tried. To add a RichMediaAnnotation with multiple assets. But I am not able to get the addtional files into the pdf document to Support the main SWF file.